# Rails Button_tag not submitting edit form, but submits new form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using the following to submit my form when creating a product.

```
<%= button_tag("Create", type: "submit", form: 'new_product') %>
```

However, the issue I am facing is that when I try to do the same for editing a product, the form does not submit at all.

```
<%= button_tag("Create", type: "submit", form: 'edit_product') %>
```

My question is, what am I missing from this not to submit the edit form? I mean when I press the button, **nothing** happens at all. haha

I know there's bound to be simple answer thanks in advance

**UPDATE:** 
So it turns out Rails sets the ID of the form to `form: 'edit_product_3'` so it adds on the ID of the item that is being edited to the form's ID.

Tested using

```
<%= button_tag("Create", type: "submit", form: 'edit_product_3') %>
```

And this fixed the issue of it not submitting.

Comment: Coukd you please add the relevant data from your view(s) to the question? People will be guessing a little without it :)

Comment: I have updated now with how I fixed it. A really simple thing as I thought. But will be useful for others too I think.

Comment: Great, glad you've got it sorted. If that's a working solution, feel free to answer and accept your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `form:` option includes the ID of the form and the ID of the product that is being edited.